# Como desativar responsivo de um site em css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, mobile

Olá, gostaria de saber se é possível desativar o responsivo de um site em jquery sem alterar os códigos por exemplo forçar a versão desktop em dispositivos móveis!

desde já agradeço!

Comment: Se tiver configurado no CSS, nos Medias Queries, eu acho que não tem como.

Comment: Possui essa meta tag no seu head:  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`? Se sim, experimente tirar e ver o que acontece

Comment: Eu diria mais, tente fazer assim: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1280">`

Comment: se eu remover as tags `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` ele tira o responsivo só que o menu desse isso no android no windows phone ele funciona normalmente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responsividade é uma coisa e adaptativo é outra, tem que ter certeza qual é o que está usando, no caso de responsividade **não tem como** sem mexer em alguma parte no código, você pode por exemplo ajustar a largura do `<body>`, adicione algo como:

```
<style>
body {
    min-width: 1024px !important; /* força largura minima de 1024px*/
}
</style>
```

Desta maneira você não precisa mexer em nada do código, basta adicionar ou remover este elemento.

Alguns efeitos responsivos funcionam atráves do tamanho do view-port e não do elemento `<body>`, mas para maioria dos "frameworks" como [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) (bootstrap2 e 3) quase tudo se baseia pela largura do elemento "pai" aonde está os elementos com classe `col-` por exemplo.

Se o site for adaptativo a única maneira é determinar o que leva ele a apresentar o HTML e CSS alternativos.

Answer (score -3):

Cara, eu acho que vai depender muito de como vc está desenvolvendo o seu CSS.
Procure CSS3 @media Rule. Vc consegue aplicar estilo somente quando for um desktop, impressora, projetor, celular, etc. E tem tbm estilo por tamanho de tela. No caso, vc aplicaria estilo somente quando a tela do usuário for maior ou menor que um determinado tamanho (vc especifica na @media).

Comment: -1 por resposta fraca, tente comentários. A maioria das respostas devem ter pelo menos um exemplo ou código.